# angularjs http post with angular and GAE

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I require a small fix. I simply need to POST my data (comments) to the datastore (GAE) using angularjs but it's not happening just yet. What's wrong with the following angularjs "post" or html?

**ANGULAR:**

```
$scope.addComment = function() {

        var form_comment = $scope.formFields.comment

        var payload = {
            comment: form_comment
        }

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/exp'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.comments.push(payload);


        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });

    };
```

**HTML:**

```
{% extends "home.html"%}
{% block content %}


<div ng-controller="commentController" class="formcontent">
    <div class ="container">

            <form ng-submit="addComment()" method="post" id="frmComment">

                <textarea ng-model="formFields.comment" id="comment" name="commento" class="form-control status-box sameline" rows="2" placeholder="Recommend Colin"></textarea>
            </form>
            <div class="button-group pull-right sameline">
                    <p class="counter">140</p>
                    <button form ="frmComment"class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul class="posts">
            <li ng-repeat = "c in comments">
                    {< c.comment >}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**PYTHON:**

```
class expHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        title="Colin_MK: Experience"
        recommendations = Recommendation.query()
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps([rec.to_dict() for rec in recommendations]))
        template_vars = {'title': title, 'recommendations': recommendations}
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/exp.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_vars))

    def post(self):
        r = json.loads(self.request.body)

        new_comment = Recommendation(comment=r['comment'])
        new_comment.put()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/bio', bioHandler),
    ('/exp', expHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature to the post method is the following:

```
post(url, data, [config]);
```

so you should also include the payload. Try something like this:

```
$http.post('/exp', payload).then(...)
```

Also, on the **then()** method of the promise, you should send a reference to the method:

```
      .then(function(response) {
          $scope.comments.push(payload);
      }, function(response) {

      });
```

Comment: That was quick thanks @sabinstefanescu... Learning curve is steep! I'd like you point you to the next issue I'm struggling with? To do with fetching the comments in my jinja2 template..Let me know